# Request or Session scope in Spring Websocket

Tags: spring, scope, spring-websocket

From WebSocket Endpoint I try to call Singleton Service.
But I an unable to use Request or Session scope from WebSocket.

(@Scope( value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS))

I get **Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread;**
For 'request' or 'session' scope on any 'ScopedProxyMode'.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For web sockets there are no request/response so the request scope is invalid. They introduced new scope called websocket in Spring 4.1. @Scope(name = "websocket", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS). Example reference link

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-stomp-websocket-scope

Comment: While I'm aware of this new scope, it doesn't help retrieve data (e.g. currently logged in user) that already exists in the outside session scope.  Any ideas how to access that? My client is sending the cookies that associate with my server session scope during the http handshake for its initial connection, but how do I find that scope from within Spring?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Spring, but if you built your web socket code to JSR-356 standard (which spring should understand) you can add a custom configurator to the endpoint definition where you can intercept the handshake. See `javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig, HandshakeRequest, HandshakeResponse)` then you may be able to get your hands on the actual session object but that would depend on your application server. You can definitely get any parameters and headers.

This is the immediate answer, however the better design approach would be to remove any reliance on sessions in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@Scope(name = "websocket", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

But it is also singleton, not session scope.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html